# Is there a way to scroll to a cell in a collectionView with animation and without showing all the cells in between?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

#### Problem description:

I'm using a segmented controller that holds the months of a year
and a collection view with cells that take the size of the `viewController`.
When I choose a month, the `collectionView` scrolls to the relevant month Cell. So far so good.

---

#### Question:

Is there a way for the `collectionView` to animate just the **one** scroll?
So say, I'm on January and I want to see July. Is there a way to just animate one "right" movement without blowing past February through June?

Comment: You can first go to one month before without animating and after add another scroll with animation to one month to another

Comment: But in that case, you'd see a quick stutter-like refresh of data before having the actual scroll animation.

Comment: Interesting! But if the cells (February - June) need to be not present while animating, then the animation is useless. Even if that was possible to accomplish as you want, you won't feel any animation at all I guess. So think about just not animating the scroll.

Comment: Are you trying to show a "continuous" calendar in a collection view? Months *and* years? That would make for a very, very wide collection view... Another approach: use a `UIPageViewController`, each month is a page... if you want to "scroll Jan->July" without seeing the months in-between, use `.setViewControllers()` with the July page.

Comment: @DonMag I'll try the `UIPageViewController` approach.
But would it matter that you have many `UICollectionViewCell`s? the only thing in those cells is like two labels wouldn't it be lighter than loading more `UIViewController`s?

Comment: @DonMag The `PageViewController` solution worked perfectly, thanks!